# How to detect when an LED has burned out?

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, hall-effect, detection

I'd like to have a way to detect when a low power LED burns out (2-3.5V, 200-400mA) that is being driven using PWM from a Raspberry Pi with a MOSFET.

My understanding is that I would be able to accomplish this by measuring the current to the LED and seeing if it is near zero in the middle of an "on" cycle, but I don't know if that's how this is typically done or if there is a lighter weight solution (considering I would want to do this with ~50 LEDs in total.) I've been told a Hall effect sensor can be used to measure the current, but I've also been told that they don't work well at this low current.

What would a typical solution for detecting a burnt out LED look like?

Comment: Since you should be driving it from a current source, measure the voltage across it when ON. Too low : failed short (other diodes do, don't know if LEDs ever do). Too high : failed open.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient just to notice that it doesn't work?

Comment: @Andyaka How else is it meant to know to phone/email home and get a replacement part ordered and an engineer booked? I think that's the sort of thing that's happened with some IT equipment for many decades (with appropriate maintenance contracts, of course).

Comment: @Andyaka While trying to stay brief enough for a comment, in my application the LEDs are generally not visible to the operator and are used to warn other people that the device is in use. It's almost like brake lights on a car, except in this case there is no redundancy of multiple lights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BrianDrummond's suggestion is best. Find a range for the Vf at your current and (and over the applicable junction temperature range) apply a window comparator to the voltage. We use exactly that method to detect failure in an IR LED (or connections to it) since the obvious "visual" indication is not available.

I've seen partial failures in some LEDs that result in dim light and a substantial change in Vf. Maybe something to do with the heterojunction structure or just a partial short.

Window comparator from [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html) website. Open-collector (or open-drain) comparators such as [LM339](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM339-D.PDF) should be used, or diodes added. Note that quad comparator pinout is different from quad op-amp pinout.

[image]

Comment: Or multiplex all the LED voltages into an ADC for much less hardware, but more software.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, we just used a free ADC channel. Shared with an ISP pin, so it added a single resistor (which was an unused part of an x4 array).